# Cordova Android Builds Failing

Tags: android, cordova

I spun up a new Cordova project following the instructions at https://cordova.apache.org/#getstarted

when I run `cordova build android --verbose` I get the following output:

`No scripts found for hook "before_build".
No scripts found for hook "before_prepare".
Checking config.xml and package.json for saved platforms that haven't been added to the project
Config.xml and package.json platforms are the same. No pkg.json modification.
Package.json and config.xml platforms are different. Updating config.xml with most current list of platforms.
PlatformApi successfully found for platform android
Android Studio project detected
Checking config.xml for saved plugins that haven't been added to the project
Checking for any plugins added to the project that have not been installed in android platform
No differences found between plugins added to project and installed in android platform. Continuing...
Generating platform-specific config.xml from defaults for android at /Users/ben.carpenter/code/cordovatest/platforms/android/app/src/main/res/xml/config.xml
Merging project's config.xml into platform-specific android config.xml
Merging and updating files from [www, platforms/android/platform_www] to platforms/android/app/src/main/assets/www
Wrote out android application name "HelloCordova" to /Users/ben.carpenter/code/cordovatest/platforms/android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml
android-versionCode not found in config.xml. Generating a code based on version in config.xml (1.0.0): 10000
Wrote out Android package name "io.cordova.hellocordova" to /Users/ben.carpenter/code/cordovatest/platforms/android/app/src/main/java/io/cordova/hellocordova/MainActivity.java
This app does not have launcher icons defined
This app does not have splash screens defined
This app does not have additional resource files defined
Prepared android project successfully
No scripts found for hook "after_prepare".
No scripts found for hook "before_compile".
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/ben.carpenter/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
(node:6593) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): [object Object]
(node:6593) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejectionsthat are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.`

also when I run `cordova requirements android` I get this :

```
Android Studio project detected

Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed
avdmanager: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.(SchemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.(SchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.run(AvdManagerCli.java:213)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.main(AvdManagerCli.java:200)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
        ... 5 more
Gradle: installed /usr/local/Cellar/gradle/4.7/bin/gradle
(node:6724) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): [object Object]
(node:6724) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejectionsthat are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I have tried installing various Android SDK platforms, I've tried Android studio 2.3 and 3.1. I've read all kinds of questions here and on the cordova and ionic forums but nothing so far has helped.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using **Java 10**? I understand that Cordova requires [JDK 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html), so try installing that version instead then update your `JAVA_HOME` accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is some issue in your JDK version. Try installing JDK 8 and update your JAVA_HOME path.